# how to escape and  save data to simpledb in node.js 

Tags: node.js, amazon-simpledb, html-escape-characters

I am using simpldb  and am trying to save  `rahul' mehta` in simpledb but it is giving me error below : 
Code :

```js
   function htmlEscape(text) {
     return text.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').
         replace(/</g,'&lt;').
         replace(/"/g,'&quot;').
         replace(/'/g,'&#039;');
    }
    console.log(params.filename);

  if (params.filename!=undefined) params.filename=htmlEscape(params.filename);
    console.log(sys.inspect(params));
  sdb.putItem(domain, params.objectid, params, function( error ) {
  });
```

Output :

```
rahul' mehta

{ 
  filename: 'rahul&#039; mehta',
  }
```

Error :

```
   {"event":"error","errno":"InvalidQueryExpression","message":"The specified query expression syntax is not valid.","queueno":7}
```

Why this error is coming , how can i solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because you are trying to run **Amazon SimpleDB SELECT Query** and syntax of that query is wrong. This may be because in query -- **Attribute Value** -- must be unclosed with **single quote**s i.e. 'Attribute Value', and again if -- **Domain Name** -- and -- **Attribute Name** -- contains any special characters then they must be unclosed with acute i.e `Domain Name` OR `Attribute Name`. I think you are able to save **rahul' mehta** but when you are trying to get that saved attribute-value, you are getting this error. [image: There is nothing wrong this with string you can see it has been saved successfully using SDB Explorer] http://www.sdbexplorer.com/